# How to not display @ character between ASP.NET inline tags

Tags: asp.net, eval

```
<asp:Label CssClass="info" ID="Label2" runat="server"> <%# Eval("Title")%></asp:Label>

<asp:Label CssClass="info" ID="Label1" runat="server">@<%# Eval("Company")%></asp:Label>
```

When both the Title and the Company have a value, the code above produces sth like:

Engineer @ABC COMPANY

When the company is null looks like:

Engineer @

I want to get rid of the @ symbol if Company does not have any value. Tried ternary operator but failed. Please give it a solution!

EDIT:

```
<%if (Eval("Company")!=null)
  {%>
      @<%# Eval("Company")%>
<% } %>
```

This is one I attempted
Gives the runtime error:  `Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control`.

The other go:

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Company").ToString()) ? "@ Eval("Company")" :Eval("Company") )%>
```

Comment: Can you show the attempt you made which "failed" and describe what it did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a *long* time since I'd had to use WebForms, but I imagine you were closest here:

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Company").ToString()) ? "@ Eval("Company")" : Eval("Company") )%>
```

However, note that your call to `Eval("Company")` in the first result of the condition is *inside a string*.  This has two problems.  First, code which is inside of a string literal doesn't get executed as code.  Second, the string literal is broken since you're using double-quotes inside of double-quotes.

You'd need to break apart the string literal from the code:

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Company").ToString()) ? "@ " + Eval("Company") : Eval("Company") )%>
```

It also seems to me that the last call to `Eval("Company")` is superfluous since you'd already testing it to be an empty string, so you can simplify:

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Company").ToString()) ? "@ " + Eval("Company") : string.Empty )%>
```